# PHP realpath on Windows Case Issue

Tags: php, windows, symlink

I have a symlink on my Windows server which was made like this:

```
F:\>mkdir link-target
F:\>mklink /D link f:\link-target
```

*(Note the lower case `f:` in the symlink target)*

In PHP I run this:

```
$dir = realpath('f:\link');
var_dump($dir);

$dir = realpath($dir);
var_dump($dir);
```

Which outputs:

```
string 'f:\link-target' (length=14)
string 'F:\link-target' (length=14)
```

Notice the change in case on the second realpath.

Is this a bug, or intended? And whats the best way to work around it?

It is breaking a case like this:

```
function check_link($to, $from) {
    if (realpath($to) !== realpath($from)) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Which is used to check `$to` exists, and is linked to `$from`.

- PHP 5.4
- Windows 7

**Edit:**

I need consistent behavior on both Windows and Linux, and have the following work around be its pretty nasty:

```
if (realpath($from) === false) {
} elseif (realpath($to) === false) {
} else {
    do {
        $to = realpath($to);
    } while (realpath($to) !== false && $to !== realpath($to));
    do {
        $from = realpath($from);
    } while (realpath($from) !== false && $from !== realpath($from));
    if ($to !== $from) {
        ...
    }
}
```

**Edit 2:**

On furter investigation I have noticed that on Windows symlinks are only followed 1 level deep:

```
// F:\>mkdir link-target
// F:\>mklink /D link f:\link-target 
// F:\>mklink /D link2 f:\link

$dir = realpath('f:\link2');
var_dump($dir);

$dir = realpath($dir);
var_dump($dir);

$dir = realpath($dir);
var_dump($dir);

// string 'f:\link' (length=7)
// string 'f:\link-target' (length=14)
// string 'F:\link-target' (length=14)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out

```
do {
    $to = realpath($to);
} while (realpath($to) !== false && $to !== realpath($to));
```

is the only way.

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61933

Comment: This should be faster: `while ( $to=realpath($from) and $to !== $from ) { $from = $to; }`

Answer (score 0):

This makes sense, if you think it through.  For the first path resolution, it is finding what was defined as the link target.  For the second, you end up with the same path, but one with the proper upper-case for the drive letter.

Under Windows file systems, paths/file names are case insensitive.  To compare them, just convert both to upper or lower case before testing.

```
if (strtoupper(realpath($to)) !== strtotupper(realpath($from))) {
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, the work around needs to be consistent on both Windows and Linux, hence can't just `strtolower` them. And also I would presume that the `realpath` function should always return the same thing, the absolute path.

Comment: @Petah never the less as Brad points out - Windows is case insensitive, so you have no guarantees that two strings will be identical.  Perhaps you should detect the environment in your comparison.

Comment: @Petah, I see what you're getting at, but I don't think `realpath()` is wrong in returning what path the symlink was defined for.  In any case, to compare paths properly, you are going to have to check the file system and/or platform to see if it's one that cares about case-sensitive paths.

Comment: @Rudu you are right, I could sniff the OS, and if there is no better work around I might have to.

Comment: Just noticed that symlinks are only followed 1 level deep, so the case conversion would not work (that simply) anyway.